# Should web api methods be async or not and if so how

Tags: vb.net, api

I am quite new to web api - i have got a web api working in visual basic in visual studio 2017.  It is all working fine, but I wondering if its possible or neccesary to make web api methods async.

Currently mine aren't async, and i cant find any reference as to if they should be async or not (the api would be called using async ajax from other places in the end)

how would this web api method be made async?

```
<HttpGet>
<Route("testing/dbtest1")>
Public Function DBTestGet() As List(Of MediaItem)
    Dim m As New List(Of MediaItem)()
    Using dt As DataTable = dbutils.getDataTable("uspMedia", New Dictionary(Of String, Object)())
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            m = (
                From r As DataRow In dt.Rows
                Select New MediaItem() With {
                    .Id = CType(r("Id"), Guid),
                    .DateCreated = DateTime.Parse(r("datecreated").ToString()),
                    .displayname = CStr(r("displayname")),
                    .originalfilename = CStr(r("originalfilename"))
                }).ToList()
        End If
    End Using
    Return m
End Function
```

Simon

Comment: I would assume that web api calls should generally be async, regardless of what language they are written in, because this will prevent waiting for a request to finish before running the rest of the code, i.e. it'll generally be faster. I am no expert vb.net though.

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/how-to-call-a-web-service-asynchronously

Comment: `Dim dt As DataTable = Await dbutils.getDataTableAsync("uspMedia", New Dictionary(Of String, Object)())` would make it async, and is *probably* where you want to `Await` but without knowing the implementation of `dbutils.getDataTable` it's hard to know for sure.